# How do you convert SQL mm/dd/yy to mm/dd only?

Tags: sql, datetime

How do you convert SQL mm/dd/yy datetime to mm/dd only? On Microsoft server.

Thanks all.

Comment: Since you have specified an input format, the input must already be a string. Simply truncate with `cast(dateIn as char(5))`.

Comment: You could include `style` also in order to be sure in case the format of your date is different say `yy/mm/dd`. See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/769c00/1)

Answer (score 3):

With dates and times it is an extremely common mistake to believe that what you see is what is stored. If the field is date, datetime, smalldatetime or datetime2 then what is stored are integers, not strings. So if the field is one of these, then:

```
convert(varchar(5),[date_field],1)
```

or

```
format([date_field],'MM/dd') -- mssql 2012 onward
```

If the information is a string already then left() will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specified an input format, the input must already be a string. Simply truncate with

```
cast(dateIn as char(5)).
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you sir. Would you mind breaking down the "char as (5)" part?

Comment: You desire exactly 5 characters, and `char()` is marginally more efficient than `varchar()` when it can be used. Otherwise this is simply standard syntax for the SQL `cast()` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` to just return the day and month:

```
SELECT LEFT('12/12/2000', 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't directly answering your question the way you asked it, but the best advice I can give is:  **Don't.**

Instead, send back the field in its native `datetime` type.  The database is not the place to be doing formatting.  Instead, format the date in your application code.

For example, if you are calling SQL Server from a C#/.NET application, you could retrieve the value from a `DataReader` like this:

```cs
DateTime dt = (DateTime) reader["YourDateTime"];
```

Then you would format it as a string like this:

```cs
string s = dt.ToString("MM/dd");
```

This will ensure that the date is formatted correctly.   If you are using a different language to call SQL Server, there are probably similar methods in that language.

One of the problems with the other approach mentioned (trunacating the string) is that the original value might not be formatted in mm/dd/yyyy to begin with.  That all depends on the environment settings where the SQL Server is running.  If you run the same code on an environment with dd/mm/yyyy settings, you would have unexpected results.  This is avoided by using the native data type, the way I described.